# Access Layout of another activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I made a music player and here is the design snapshot

[My app design](http://i57.tinypic.com/xfuts1.jpg)

design at the bottom is common for all tabs.

here is the xml file for tabhost and common design

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            >
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TabWidget>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider" >

        </FrameLayout>
        
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Player"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/light_grey"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="5dp"
            android:weightSum="1" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/song_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                android:text="@string/all_you_need_is_love"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/player_art"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/song_title"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/player_thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/nocover"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/art_image" />
            </LinearLayout>
            
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/player_art"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/player_art"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                >
                <SeekBar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/player_art"
                android:layout_below="@+id/seekbar"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                >
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/previous"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/rsz_previous"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/play_button"
                />
                
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/play"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/rsz_play"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/play_button"
                />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/next"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/rsz_next"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/play_button"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and another xml file is used for showing songs named music_tab.xml

Here is my java file and Allsong contains all songs title

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
MainView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.music, null, false);

SongName = (TextView) MainView.findViewById(R.id.song_title);

SongName.setText(Allsong.get(position));
String prev = SongName.getText();
```

It does not set the song Title on design but  the prev string that is having the value previously set by setText() Method.
Please anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I too have researched on this thing a lot with no result. The conclusion I came upon was that a class can access only those widgets that are present in the layout which it inflates.

Answer (score 0):

***As per my Knowledge, This is not possible !***

- Say you have `WIDGET-A` in **ClassA**
- In order to access `WIDGET-A` in say **ClassB**, you have to pass the
  object from **ClassA** to **ClassB**(Eg: using intents) and then
  manipulate it